# KeyError in flask web service

Tags: python, flask, postman

I have created FLASK web service to upload an image but I'm getting an error when I try to call it using POSTMAN.

Getting an error

```
400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'file1'
```

But I am sure I have same key name at both the places.

My Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
import numpy as np
import cv2
from imutils import paths
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/img", methods=['POST'])
def search():

    file = request.files['file1']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(filename)

    images = list(paths.list_images("data"))

    query_image = cv2.imread(filename)
    query_image = cv2.cvtColor(query_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    q_hist = get_histogram(query_image)

    hist = []

    for i in images:
        image = cv2.imread(i)

        # convert the images to grayscale
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        s_hist = get_histogram(image)
        dist = wasserstein_distance(q_hist, s_hist)
        hist.append(dist)

    x = min(hist)
    print(hist)
    if x > 2:
        return "Image Not Found"
    else:
        idx = hist.index(x)
        matched_img = images[idx]
        return des[matched_img]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is how I am calling the web service using postman

[image: Postman Image]

Headers

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It's not directly related, just re-read the question, but good to have anyways

Comment: Try adding if request.method=='POST'  as first line of function

Comment: Also what is the size of file you trying to process?

Comment: Also can you show the headers you are sending?

Comment: In screenshot it shows 9 headers..

Comment: Try printing request.files see if it shows anything.

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation It's printing `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

Comment: Use request.files.to_dict()

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation  giving empty `dict`

Comment: Add header Content-Type multipart/form-dataitem

Comment: Remove `Content-Type: application/json` heade

Comment: Just for sake of confirming. Use curl.. curl -X POST -F file1=@"/path/to/my/file/a.jpg" http://localhost:5000/img

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation   Strange ...getting response here.

Comment: Yeah probably the postman isnt sending correct request. It appends temp headers which modifies your request and stops it from processing. Your code will work fine once you integrate it to front end. :)

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts :-)

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation you can post it as answer. I will accept it

Comment: Thankyou, and all the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman might be sending additional headers with your request.
Just for sake of testing your code use curl..

> curl -X POST -F file1=@"/path/to/my/file/a.jpg"
>   http://localhost:5000/img

Probably the postman isn't sending the correct request. It appends temp headers which modifies your request and stops it from processing. Your code will work fine once you integrate it to the front end.